# Get tensorflow autograph warning when building model by calling self-defined module

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, deep-residual-networks

I tried to build model by calling self-defined module in Google Colab, but get autoGraph warning.

## **Folder structure :**

```
drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/stackoverflow/q001/
├── train
│   └── train.ipynb          # The place where I implement model
│                            # import models.get_ResNet13(.)
│   
└── tools
    └── dl
        ├── __init__.py 
        ├── layers.py
        └── models.py        # import layers.ResidualBottleneckBlock
```

## **Code:**

**layers.py** [code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_mVfp6g2_bl3OkEREAm3tew1nKxEHkYL/view?usp=sharing)

**models.py** [code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j11ATJiMxe7M3KkS2ZltPsrznuStd_ms/view?usp=sharing)

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from .layers import ResidualBottleneckBlock

def get_ResNet13(input_shape, output_shape):
    ...
    ...ResidualBottleneckBlock()...
    ...
    return model
...
```

**train.ipynb**
[code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CSudXcn-DvRnqcR8cWIK8rw01hNBKWIx/view?usp=sharing):

```
## Mount Google Drive
import os
from google.colab import drive 
drive.mount('/content/drive') 
os.chdir("drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/stackoverflow/q001/")

## Import
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
sys.path.append('tools')
from dl import models

## Change Directory
os.chdir('train')
model = models.get_ResNet13(input_shape=(28, 28, 1), output_shape=10)
```

## **Result:**

In the last line of train.ipynb:

```
model = models.get_ResNet13(input_shape=(28, 28, 1), output_shape=10)
```

I get the following warning：

> WARNING:tensorflow:AutoGraph could not transform > and will run it as-is.
>   Please report this to the TensorFlow team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output.
>   Cause: Unable to locate the source code of >. Note that functions defined in certain environments, like the interactive Python shell do not expose their source code. If that is the case, you should to define them in a .py source file. If you are certain the code is graph-compatible, wrap the call using @tf.autograph.do_not_convert. Original error: could not get source code
>   WARNING: AutoGraph could not transform > and will run it as-is.
>   Please report this to the TensorFlow team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output.
>   Cause: Unable to locate the source code of >. Note that functions defined in certain environments, like the interactive Python shell do not expose their source code. If that is the case, you should to define them in a .py source file. If you are certain the code is graph-compatible, wrap the call using @tf.autograph.do_not_convert. Original error: could not get source code
>   ...

I have tried to add the following code, but it is not work. The version of gast in colab is already 0.2.2.

```
!pip install gast==0.2.2
```

I also found that the warning won't occur if the following code is **removed**.

```
os.chdir('train')
```

The model can still be trained. I have no idea whether I can ignore the warning or not.

Does anyone know why the warning occurred?

Comment: You can safely ignore the warning log as its intended to debug logging in AutoGraph issues. For more information please refer [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/37144)